# Do not understand the function with Express and CORS

Tags: node.js, express, cors

This is a code I found in the internet using Express and CORS:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

var corsOptionsDelegate = async (req, callback) => { 
    var corsOptions = { origin: false };
    try {
        ...
        corsOptions.origin = true;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions)
}
app.use(cors(corsOptionsDelegate));
```

I don't know how this function `callback(null, corsOptions)` process in this code.

Comment: well, this code makes no sense. Starting from the point that u using `async` and an `callback` and passing this pending promise as an argument into `cors`

Comment: That's a common Node pattern referred to as an "error-first callback". `callback(null, corsOptions)` means _"nothing went wrong (so far), please proceed using these options"_. Here's an example in the `cors` docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually do not need any function callback for simple servers.
There is a much simpler way.

```js
const whiteList = [ "https://myRealBackendUrl-1", "https://myRealBackendUrl-2" ];
// you can also pass a string here instead here instead of array
const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: process.env.NODE_ENV !== production ? "http://localhost:3000" : whiteList
  // if you are in a dev environment, you probably want something like localhost
  // if you are in a production environment, for example heroku then your backend 
  // url will be something like http://example.herokuapp.com 
  // in that case `const whiteList = [ "http://example.herokuapp.com" ];`
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

The above code should be enough for the normal use case.

As for the callback function, it is if you want to run some function of your own.

```js
var corsOptionsDelegate = async (req, callback) => { 
    var corsOptions = { origin: false };
    try {
        // you can do some dynamic check here
        // For example: check database for some conditions then allow access
        if( myDatabaseSays == true ) corsOptions.origin = true;
        else corsOptions.origin = false;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // corsOptions.origin = false;
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions) // chain it
}
```

Anyway read the docs properly for more info
[1]: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

This is just a standard callback design pattern. [Here's an article you can read](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) but also you should learn more about what design patterns are and how Node.js works. This is a very basic question you're asking here.

Comment: I know it's a callback function, but I acctually want to know what does the callback do, when I go into cors module, I found this:                                                                                                            
type CorsOptionsDelegate<T extends CorsRequest = CorsRequest> = (
        req: T,
        callback: (err: Error | null, options?: CorsOptions) => void,
    ) => void; And I want how callback process